# How to address an R-variable that stores an object of class 'name'?

Tags: r

In a larger R-Script I have to address the content of a character variable that itself is stored within a variable of class name. In the following small example, how do I have to address B to see the content of A (thus "A") and not just the name (thus A)?

```
> A <- "A"
> B <- as.name(A)
> B
A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `get` to the retrieve the value

```
get(A)
```

From 'B', we can use `eval`

```
eval(B)
#[1] "A"
```

---

The OP's example is confusing.  Just to understand it better,

```
C <- "A"
B <- as.name(C)
eval(B)
#[1] "A"
```

Comment: @user7417  I am using R 3.3.0 and this is the output I am getting.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was mutilated and I did not edit it in time. The second line must be B <- as.name("C") otherwise I get the message "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Object 'A' not found". Anyway, thanks for the eval hint, I'll check it out in my script!